# Doing something in sleep mode

Tags: android

I check for new messages in the site by using the JSON

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

public void run() {
                notif();              
                }

             }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But the check does not work in sleep mode. Than it is possible to replace?

Comment: Doing network I/O every minute is very bad for the battery. Are you planning on switching to FCM for push messaging? Or, are you planning on reducing the frequency (e.g., once per hour)? Or, are you going to allow the user to choose the frequency, so users can tailor the amount of battery use tied to your app?

Comment: I will carry out checks then once per hour. 1 minute - this test period

Answer (score 2):

If your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, use `JobScheduler`.

If your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, and you are tied into using the Play Services SDK for other reasons, [use `firebase-job-dispatcher`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android).

If your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, and you would prefer not to be tied into using the Play Services SDK, [use Evernote's `android-job` library](https://github.com/evernote/android-job), which uses `JobScheduler` where it can and gracefully degrades to `AlarmManager` where it cannot.

Bear in mind that Doze mode and app standby, on Android 6.0+, will prevent you from doing periodic work, except during device-defined "idle maintenance windows", which may be once every few hours.

You can read more about scheduled work in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html).

Comment: Sorry I'm just starting to work with android. How do I know minSdkVersion?

Comment: In terms of what you have right now, if you are using Android Studio, and have a typical Android Studio project, look in `app/build.gradle`, where you will find a `minSdkVersion` line. Or, go into File > Project Structure, click on your module in the list on the left, click on the Flavors tab, and look at the "Min Sdk Version" drop-down. But, more importantly, you need to **choose** a `minSdkVersion`, based on what versions of the Android OS you want to support. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).